# Select a <input name=""> containing [ ] in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have a simple question:

*HTML:*

`<input type="checkbox" name="contacts">`

*JAVASCRIPT:*

`$("input[@name=contacts]").each(function()`
`...`

**IF** 
*HTML:*

`<input type="checkbox" name="contacts[]">`

*JAVASCRIPT:*

`???`

This is my question.

Comment: Note, `@name` doesn't work in jQuery 1.3+, just remove the `@`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add quotes for the value in attribute selector:

```
$("input[@name='contacts[]']").each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: There should be no @, unless the OP is using an ancient version of jQuery.

Comment: @epascarello I have also thought about that, but finally decided not to remove if the first example works fine for the OP.